# Entering Sum in traditional form

Tags: notebooks, formatting

The documentation for `Sum` says that it is possible to replace `Sum` by <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>sum</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. The limits ($i_\max$ and $i_\min$) should be entered as underscript $i=i_\min$ below $\sum$ and overscript $i_\max$ over $\sum$

Following the aforementioned rules, I entered the formula as:

```
 Cell[BoxData[
 UnderscriptBox[
  RowBox[{
   OverscriptBox["\[Sum]", "10"], "q"}], 
  RowBox[{"q", "=", "1"}]]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.572528196734789*^9, 3.572528215609144*^9}},
 EmphasizeSyntaxErrors->True]
```

which gives an error

> Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .

How do I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to enter sums with limits is to use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Esc</kbd>`sumt`<kbd>Esc</kbd> (see the Advanced Math Assistant palette). Then you get a template that can be filled by tabbing between the placeholders.

Answer (score 5):

You probably entered <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>&</kbd> to create the under and over scripts individually. You can see in your code that this is what happened, because of the presence of `UnderscriptBox` and `OverscriptBox`.

Instead, what you need is `UnderoverscriptBox`, which is obtained by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>&</kbd>), followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>. This automatically creates the opposite script and associates it as a single `UnderoverscriptBox` instead of separate under/over scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be entering the lower and upper limits incorrectly.

From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sum.html) for `Sum`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: documentation specified overscript as [Ctrl]+7. Replacing with Ctrl+% works. Thanks